# Any tool for viewing historical process resource utilization? (IE: A combination of sar and pidstat)

Tags: linux, process, top, sar, sysstat

I'm trying to troubleshoot some CPU spikes that occur every so often on a Linux server. I can use ***`sar`*** to see the resource utilization in the past, and ***`pidstat`*** to see what processes are using what resources, but `pidstat` doesn't go into the past.

So what I'm looking for is a combination of both - Something that I can use to see what processes were taking up what resources. I haven't been able to find anything, and I know I can write a simple bash script to save the output of pidstat to a file, but if there's already a solution for this (which I would be surprised if there isn't), then I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be something of a case of deer hunting with a howitzer, but you can do what you're looking for with Splunk ingesting server logs and the like; you can then very easily pull out and even rapidly chart the data over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`atop`](http://www.atoptool.nl/) does what your are looking for. It logs process resource utilization at intervals of your choice, and you can go back in time to see what happened at a specific time (`atop -r logfile -b time` then use <kbd>t</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd>).

Comment: I was just comming back to answer my own question with **atop**, haha.  Thank you! I was hoping to be able to test it on my macbook, but it doesnt look like theres an OSX version of atop :-\